# select sum of columns with the same name and size

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a MySQL table like that:

```
material_name   size        rcv     issue   
abc             250mm       10      8
abc             250mm       10      8
abc             150mm       25      4
dfz             450mm       15      6
dfz             250mm       42      25
dfz             250mm       34      35
xyz             250mm       25      20
xyz             150mm       42      40
lmn             150mm       10      1
```

I'm trying to `select total rcv` and `total issue`
where both of `material_name and size` are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you want the following pair **(MATERIAL_NAME, SIZE)** to be unique. In this case, try this:

```
SELECT MATERIAL_NAME, SIZE, SUM(RCV), SUM(ISSUE)
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY MATERIAL_NAME, SIZE;
```

**Otherwise**, if you don't want to have duplicates on one column - E.g.:

```
abc 250 mm
abc 150 mm
```

you need an **additional criteria** (which one have to be ignored).

Or maybe you want to split the problem in 2 parts:

```
-- for name
SELECT MATERIAL_NAME, SUM(RCV), SUM(ISSUE)
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY MATERIAL_NAME, SIZE;

-- for size
SELECT SIZE, SUM(RCV), SUM(ISSUE)
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY MATERIAL_NAME, SIZE;
```

Comment: Thanks Curiosu, it works for me.
but can you explain me GROUP BY Key word briefly??

Comment: Group By simply means that those columns define the group.  So you get one row in the output for every unique combination of the group by columns in the data set.  Not that as soon as you use group by then all columns in the result must either be group by columns or some form of agregrate function (sum, max, min, etc.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edited my post to include that case, but I really think that he wants to measure something for a given material specified by name & size.

Comment: yes right. and now i understand GROUP BY Key Word. thank you so much CURIOSU.